# Not able to show h3 tag in two rows inside a flex div container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using following example and i need to use two title in the page for each item.
`<div>` div inside `li` is defined as flex and if i add more than one element it show it as two columns but i want to in two rows and center aligned horizontally & vertically.

If i change the flex to block or other property then title move to top while i want them in center

Not sure how to fix it with minimal css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNqYWd

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
             <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
             <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
         <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-direction` and `justify-content` property, like:

```
.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
  flex-direction: column; /* Flex Direction Column */
  justify-content: center; /* Vertically Aligns Content (on flex-direction: column) */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*Use full screen*):

```css
.cbp-rfgrid {
 margin: 35px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 16.6666667%; /* Fallback */
 width: -webkit-calc(100% / 6);
 width: calc(100% / 4);
  margin:1px;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a,
.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* Flexbox is used for centering the heading */
.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 top: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 bottom: 20px;
 background: rgba(71,163,218,0.2);
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -moz-align-items: center;
 -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a:hover div {
 opacity: 1;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Example for media query: change number of items per row */

@media screen and (max-width: 1190px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 20%; /* Fallback */
  width: -webkit-calc(100% / 5);
  width: calc(100% / 5);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 945px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 25%; /* Fallback */
  width: -webkit-calc(100% / 4);
  width: calc(100% / 4);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 33.3333333%; /* Fallback */
  width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 33.3333333%; /* Fallback */
  width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);
  width: calc(100% / 3);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 50%; /* Fallback */
  width: -webkit-calc(100% / 2);
  width: calc(100% / 2);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
             <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
             <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
         <h3>Heading One</h3>
      <h3>Date</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400">
      <div>
        <h3>Felis catus</h3></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh That simple. Great

Comment: @Learning Updated my answer, please have a look at it agin.

Comment: I was wondering why it was not working thanks for updating your answer